# How to choose between multiple make.exe to build

Tags: makefile

I have multiple make.exe on my computer. How can I specify which one I use to build my code?
Can I copy the one (make.exe) to the folder of my code , then run:
make -f Makefile *** ?

Thanks.

Comment: if I enter the folder of my code then do: c:\make.exe -f Makefile, I got: make.exe: ***No rule to make target 'Makefile', stop.

Comment: Does `Makefile` in fact exist in that folder? Or `makefile` or `MAKEFILE` or `mAKeFiLE`?

Comment: What are you make:ing i.e. what's your programming language and environment ?

Comment: Sure, it is there. If I just run make -f Makefile , it is all right. But when I specify make.exe, I got the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only plan on using one of your make.exe set the PATH environment variable so it points to the one you want to use.

If you plan on using different make.exe for different projects add a .BAT file to your project directory and use the full path to the make.exe in there

example bat file:

```
@echo off
c:\somepath\somewhere\make.exe %*
```

Use it like this:

1. cd to the project directory where the make.bat file resides
2. make -f Makefile